# Error while copying S3 object from one key to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have been trying to clone the S3 objects from one key to another, using AWS Ruby sdk (v2). The problem is, the target destination is not present; and it throws me error that

```
Aws::S3::Errors::NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist.
```

I am curious to know, how does AWS CLI sync method copies and syncs the objects between two different S3 buckets, or in same bucket as well.

Below, is the snippet of the code I am using to perform the job.

```
s3_bucket = Aws::S3::Bucket.new(
    name: [BUCKET_NAME],
    region: [S3_BUCKET_REGION],
    credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(
      [ACCESS_KEY_ID],
      [SECRET_ACCESS_KEY]
      )
    )

  source_bucket_object = s3_bucket.object(s3_source_key)
  target_bucket_object = s3_bucket.object(s3_target_key)

  target_bucket_object.copy_from(source_bucket_object.key, acl: 'public-read')
```

I also tried doing it in below way, but it didn't helped a bit;

```
target_bucket_object.copy_from(copy_source: "#{target_bucket_object.bucket_name}/#{source_bucket_object.key}")
```

Please help me, in tackling this issue.Also, if there is an alternate way to accomplish this; do suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Nishant

Comment: The two buckets are in 2 different AWS account or same AWS account?

Comment: The part about `.copy_from(source_bucket_object.key,` seems wrong, for sure, since this looks like it's only the object key and the source bucket info would be lost.

Comment: Any resolution you'd found for this?